# How to include a expression in the name of file in Maxima

Tags: string, output, concatenation, maxima

I have a Maxima program that does some algebra and then writes some things down on an external file. How do I include some calculated values and even small expressions into the name of the file?

A mwe would be the following:

```
N:3;
f: erf(x);
tay: taylor(f,x,0,N);
with_stdout("taylor.txt", fortran(tay));
```

But this example names the file `taylor.txt`. I wanted something that named the file `taylor_N3_f_erf.txt` or something like that. I have tried several syntaxes but nothing worked.

Also, I know Maxima in programmed in lisp and I learned the syntax for concatenating strings in Lisp but I haven't figured out how to use that in Maxima.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. It took some playing around with argument quoting and evaluation in functions but I think it works now.

```
(%i2) bar (name_base, name_extension, ['vars]) := sconcat (name_base, foo(vars), ".", name_extension) $
(%i3) foo(l) := apply (sconcat, join (makelist ("_", 2 * length (l)), join (l, map (string, map (ev, l))))) $
(%i4) [a, b, c] : [123, '(x + 1), '(y/2)];
                                             y
(%o4)                           [123, x + 1, -]
                                             2
(%i5) bar ("foobar", "txt", a, b, c);
(%o5)                    foobar_a_123_b_x+1_c_y/2.txt
(%i6) myname : bar ("baz", "quux", a, b);
(%o6)                        baz_a_123_b_x+1.quux
(%i7) with_stdout (myname, print ("HELLO WORLD"));
(%o7)                             HELLO WORLD
(%i8) printfile ("baz_a_123_b_x+1.quux");
HELLO WORLD 
(%o8)                        baz_a_123_b_x+1.quux
```

Note that `sconcat` concatenates strings and `string` produces a string representation of an expression.

Division expressions could cause trouble since `/` means a directory in a file name ... maybe you'll have to subsitute for those characters or any other non-allowed characters. See `ssubst`.

Note that `with_stdout` evaluates its first argument, so if you have a variable e.g. `myname` then the value of `myname` is the name of the output file.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Still haven't been able to make `ssubst` work though. I don't know why. I have been using `fname : subst("div", "/", fname);` but the output string is the same as the input. I have also tried to escape the character.

Comment: @TomCho don't you mean `fname : ssubst("div", "/", fname)` ?? Glad to hear it works for you.